# Can gitlab be installed with Cherokee web server?

Tags: ruby, git, webserver, gitlab, cherokee

I've looked all over and can't figure out if you could use Cherokee instead of Apache or Nginx for gitlab. I'd rather not run multiple webservers (and imagine that they could conflict anyway). I'm giving this a shot on Ubuntu Server 12.10.

For the record, I've already installed gitlab with [this guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/5-4-stable/doc/install/installation.md) up to the Nginx section (with all default settings other than passwords, email addresses, and hostname). I'd like to install gitlab at git.mydomain.com and I would prefer for the local server files to be located at /var/www/git.mydomain.com, as I keep all of my domains under /var/www/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only problem turned out to be an issue with Ruby. Once that was resolved, I set up gitlab to use a port (though sockets should work too). Everything seems to work pretty well, except for an issue with pushing over HTTPS, but that might have something to do with my local Eclipse/eGit install.

So yes, gitlab will work with Cherokee.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have all of the Ruby config done, you just need to hook cherokee
up for hosting RoR by following this guide  http://cherokee-project.com/doc/cookbook_ror.html